# Prove that subset $\mathscr{B}$ of a vector space $V$ is basis for $V$...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that subset $\mathscr{B}$ of a vector space $V$ is basis for $V$ if and only if any vector $v∈V$ can be written as a unique linear combination of the elements in $\mathscr{B}$.

- So I understand that for $\mathscr{B}$ to be a basis for $V$ it must be linearly independent and it must span $V$. I am having trouble seeing how we would prove these things using what is given. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Split the condition

- *any vector $v \in V$ can be written as a unique linear combination of the elements in $\mathscr{B}$*

in two parts

1. any vector $v \in V$ can be written as a linear combination of the elements in $\mathscr{B}$, and
2. this linear combination is unique

Clearly part (1) is the same as saying that $\mathscr{B}$ spans $V$,

As to part (2), assume for simplicity that $\mathscr{B}$ is finite of order $n$, 
$$
\mathscr{B} = \{ v_{1} , \dots , v_{n} \}.
$$
(2) implies that if 
$$
a_{1} v_{1} + \dots + a_{n} v_{n}
= 0 =
0 v_{1} + \dots + 0 v_{n},
$$
then the $a_{i}$ are zero, so that the $v_{i}$ are linearly independent.

Conversely, if the $v_{i}$ are linearly independent, and 
$$
a_{1} v_{1} + \dots + a_{n} v_{n}
= 
b_{1} v_{1} + \dots + b_{n} v_{n},
$$
then
$$
(a_{1} -b_{1}) v_{1} + \dots + (a_{n}-b_{n}) v_{n} = 0,
$$
so that $a_{i} = b_{i}$ for all $i$, which is (2).